# could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using rails 3.2.13. I am getting the error below when pushing to Heroku. 
My app is working fine, I just wanted to get rid of this message when trying to update my heroku app.

Any fix for this? Or any gem causing the conflict?

**GEM FILE:**
    gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'pry'
end

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'faker'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'heroku-api'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'thin'
```

**ERROR CODE BELOW:**

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `connect'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__729555034853532426__prepare__3596797161414133270__callbacks'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
   /tmp/build_zmeoku64h79j/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
   Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
   Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable one of the labs features via `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` which will give your application access to environment variables when the slug is compiled.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile